# Dynamically add URL Scheme in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, instagram

I implemented the **Login With Instagram** in my app. I made a app on Instagram and get the Client ID and secret key for calling the API.

But as per the Instagram Document, **it has only limited API request per hour.**

So, **How can I solve this?**

**My idea:** One my solution is that the user will create his own **Client ID and Secret Key** and after that he will paste in the app to call the API.

But my problem is that **how can I add the this dynamic keys as a URL Schemes into the plist?**
I get the idea from one of the app which flows the same for Twitter API.

**Any help/Solution/reference will be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: According to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817272/editing-info-plist-possible-programmatically this is not possible to edit info.plist file. Sorry :(

Answer (score -2):

Try this but not tested..

```
NSDictionary *infoList = [[NSBundle mainBundle]infoDictionary];        

    NSDictionary *urlScheme=[[infoList valueForKey:@"CFBundleURLTypes"] objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"url scheme before:%@",urlScheme);

    [urlScheme setValue:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"New Scheme Name"] forKey:@"CFBundleURLSchemes"];

    NSLog(@"url scheme after:%@",urlScheme);
```

Comment: Info.plist file is readonly. Also you are mutating in the code above immutable object.