# How to add font in info.plist in cocos2dx while the app is running?

Tags: ios, fonts, cocos2d-x, info.plist

How can I add font style in my coco2dx app while it is on the fly?
For example the font will be downloaded from the server, after downloading the font, the downloaded font will be use in a specific Label in the app.

I know how to add font style in cocos2dx app. it should be added in the info.plist file and in the resources folder.

my problem is I need to add the font downloaded from the server in the info.plist file and I don't know how to edit the info.plist file while the app is running. And base on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817272/editing-info-plist-possible-programmatically) it is not possible. is there other way?

sorry for my bad english. please help, thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is not possible means it is not possible. You cannot write at all into the application bundle while the application is running.

Comment: is there other way? to achieve my goal?

Comment: You can save the font to the external directory.