# Change the permission usage description message during runtime

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I want to use more than one "Privacy - Microphone usage description". During runtime I want to select the appropriate one based on something.
Info.plist only accepts one string and it doesn't let you provide more than one strings and select one of those during runtime.
Is it even possible? If so, please let me know the way to achieve it.

Comment: Your best approach is probably to display your own alert to the user before requesting permission that will trigger the system alert.  You can then customise your own alert as required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change it. Since its declared in the Info.plist and this is write protected.

[Editing Info.plist possible programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817272/editing-info-plist-possible-programmatically)